# How to specify text mode in Python's tempfile.TemporaryFile()?

Tags: python, temporary-files

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html), TemporaryFile() mentions

> The returned object is a file-like object whose _file attribute is either an io.BytesIO or io.StringIO object (depending on whether binary or text mode was specified)...

However, as of Python 3.6, there is no `text=True` method of asking for text mode.   How does one do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TemporaryFile signature:

```
 tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+b', buffering=None, encoding=None, newline=None, suffix=None, prefix=None, dir=None)
```

We are interested in a `mode` parameter. The last symbol is 'b', which means binary mode. If you pass `mode='wt'`, it will be opened in a text mode.

All modes are described on this page: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open